# What is MYSQL equivalent for DATABASENAME..TABLENAME?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, equivalent

In MSSQL Server, I can execute the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME..TABLENAME
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.TABLENAME
```

What is the equivalent syntax on MYSQL to perform this SQL (DATABASE..TABLE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all the records from a database table the syntax is quite similar it's

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do below

```
SELECT * from  mydatabase1.tblName
```